# Remove the outlier in the dataset before running factor analysis in R

Tags: r

The introduction about my dataset: It is the questionnaire data, mentioning the different reasons for students' antisocial behaviours. And I want to run the factor analysis to organize similar reasons to a factor.

For instance, there is one reason that students have antisocial behaviour because of their parents' educating, and another reason is that this happens because of their parents' educational background. There are some similarity between these two reasons, so that I am wondering whether these two reasons could be merged into one factor, so I want to run a factor analysis to see whether I could merge different reasons in one factor.

In order to run the factor analysis, removing the outlier(those which is smaller than mean minus 3 standard deviation, and bigger than mean add 3 standard deviation) is quite important from my understanding. However, I am not sure whether it is necessary for the questionnaire data, and if it is necessary, or at least it is not completely redundant, then with which R code could I reach this aim?

I did some research on Median Absolute Deviation (MAD) method, which could partial out the outliers.  And I also wrote the R code as below:

`mad.mean.D.O <- as.numeric(D.O.Mean.data$D.O_Mean)`

```
median(mad.mean.D.O)

mad(mad.mean.D.O, center = median(mad.mean.D.O), constant = 1.4826,
    na.rm = FALSE, low = FALSE, high = FALSE)

print(Upper.MAD <- (median(mad.mean.D.O)+3*(mad(mad.mean.D.O, center = median(mad.mean.D.O), constant = 1.4826,
                                                na.rm = FALSE, low = FALSE, high = FALSE))))

print(Lower.MAD <- (median(mad.mean.D.O)-3*(mad(mad.mean.D.O, center = median(mad.mean.D.O), constant = 1.4826,
                                                na.rm = FALSE, low = FALSE, high = FALSE))))

D.O.clean.mean.data <- D.O.Mean.data %>%
  select(ID_t,
         anonymity,
         fail_exm,
         pregnant,
         deg_job,
         new_job,
         crowded,
         stu_req,
         int_sub,
         no_org,
         child,
         exm_cont,
         lec_sup,
         fals_exp,
         fin_prob,
         int_pro,
         family,
         illness,
         perf_req,
         abroad,
         relevanc,
         quickcash,
         deg_per,
         lack_opp,
         prac_work,
         D.O_Mean) %>%
  filter(D.O_Mean < 4.197032 & D.O_Mean > 0.282968)
```

This R code works.
However, I just wonder whether there are also other methods which could reach the same aim, but in a simpler approach.

In addition, my data set looks like this: [image]

All the variables are questionnaire data, being measured by likert scale. And all of those are reasons for antisocial behaviour. For example, the first participants, she/he give 1 to anonymity, that means from not exactly yo exactly, he/ she think anonymity not exactly contribute to his/ her antisocial behaviour.

I would be really thankful for all of your input here.

Comment: I don't think that you should be removing outliers that come from a questionnaire that seems to have a finite set of choices. And if you are trying to detect antisocial behaviour (which is an unusual behaviour) maybe those are the ones that show up as outliers.

Comment: You should share data with `dput(head(df,n))` and remove the image.

Comment: for the code dput(head(df,n)), what does the n represent? the column number? Could you share with me an example of how to share the data without the image?

Comment: Thanks for your idea. The reason I thought about removing outlier is because I know factor analysis will be easily influenced by influential outliers, but I am not sure whether it works the same with questionnaire data. So just to be safe, I would like to check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function to remove outliers.  It'll comb through all columns to identify outliers, so be sure to temporarily remove columns do not need outliers removed and you can `cbind()` it back later.

```
#identify outliers
idoutlier<- function(data, cutoff = 3) {
  # Calculate the sd
  sds <- apply(data, 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
  # Identify the cells with value greater than cutoff * sd (column wise)
  result <- mapply(function(d, s) {
    which(d > cutoff * s)
  }, data, sds)
  result
}
```

```
#remove outliers
rmoutlier<- function(data, outliers) {
  result <- mapply(function(d, o) {
    res <- d
    res[o] <- NA
    return(res)
  }, data, outliers)
  return(as.data.frame(result))
}
```

`cbind()` if necessary, and then `na.omit()` to remove your outliers